# get ancestors of source in sequence in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am using networkx version 2.1 to generate graph.

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (1, 3), (3, 6)])
```

If I check ancestors of node = 5 by `nx.ancestors(g, 5)`, It will return set `{1, 2, 4}` sometimes not in sequence e.g. `{1, 4, 2}` How to get it in sequence? Is there any way to get it in sequence?

Comment: `{...}` denotes a `set` in python, which is an unordered data structure, being a hash map underneath. You can order the result yourself if you have a particular order in mind.

Comment: Seels like you want the list of ancestors in order from your node to the root am I right ?

Comment: yes @Plopp from node to the root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your DiGraph seems like a tree (aka each node can have at most 1 parent and the only node without parent is the root).

If your real graph is a tree then the easiest way to get all the ancestors in order is to use the `shortest_path()` function.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (1, 3), (3, 6)])
nx.shortest_path(g, source=1, target=5)
# return [1,2,4,5] which is the list of all nodes from root 1 to my node 5
```

If you do not know the root of your ***tree*** then an easy way to find it is to look for the only node with an `in_degree` equals to 0. Something like:

```
def get_root(g):
    for node, indegree in g.in_degree():
         if indegree == 0:
              # if you'r graph is a tree you only have one root so you don't need to check every node, once you find it it's done
              return node
```

Or just the first element in a topological sort: `next(nx.topological_sort(g))`

If your graph is not a tree you may need to define a new recursive method using `predecessors()` (or `successors()` depending on how you do your method)

EDIT: changed the code to use your example